# Retrieve original IdP token to call IdP APIs when using Okta

Tags: oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, okta

For an app I am working on, I would like to call the Microsoft Graph API but with the token provided by Okta, even after a login through Microsoft IdP, this is not possible.

Does anyone know if is it possible (and is the correct approach) to retrieve the original token generated by an IdP and use it to call some IdP API?

Something like this:  https://auth0.com/docs/connections/calling-an-external-idp-api

Answer (score 0):

If anyone else needs it, I have found an Okta API that allows you to get the original token generated by IdP.

https://developer.okta.com/docs/reference/api/idps/#social-authentication-token-operation

With that I am now able to correctly call the Microsoft Graph APIs.